# What is the data size for DATE, DATETIME and TIMESTAMP data types in Google BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

Does anyone know how many bytes does BigQuery use to store `DATE`, `DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP` data types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is answered in the pricing [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#data):

```
DATE       - 8 bytes 
DATETIME   - 8 bytes 
TIMESTAMP  - 8 bytes
```